# Converting 1D array to 2D array. Image input as 1D array

Tags: c++, image-processing

Image coming in a 1D array data. Need to migrate it to 2D data. The 2D array must be of size 640 rows and 1176 columns and must be finally written to a file with the .pgm header.

```
void saveFile(unsigned short* mImStack)  // Image to be accessed
{
    std::ofstream f("D:\\tester.txt", ios::out);

    int rows = 0;
    int cols = 0;

    int t_rows = (mImageRaw->m_ImageHeight); // height of image (640)
    int t_cols = (mImageRaw->m_ImageWidth); // width of image (1176)

    int ncells = t_rows * t_cols; // total cells of the 1D array which has the image data

    unsigned short** mImage2D = new unsigned short*[cols];  // defining a 2D array
    for (int i = 0; i < t_cols; ++i)
    {
        mImage2D[i] = new unsigned short[rows];
    }
    for (int n = 0; n < ncells; n++)
    {
        mImage2D[rows][cols] = mImStack[n];  // Error ocuring here as Access violation reading location 
        cols++;
        if (cols == t_cols && rows != t_rows + 1)
        {
            rows++;
            cols = 0;
        }
    }

    f << "P2\n" << t_rows << " " << t_cols << "\n4096\n" << mImage2D[rows][cols];
    f.close();
}
```

Comment: you should be using t_rows and t_cols in your mImage2D new statements, not rows and cols

Comment: @Benjymous: It works partially when I append the code with t_rows and t_cols, but the file to be generated is only with the last generated value. But I need it in the format exactly how it looks in the 2D array. Also, I have checked using a standalone program with the same code which rather reads a text file which gives the same problem.

Comment: "but the file to be generated is only with the last generated value" - do you mean you're only seeing a single value being written out?  That's not surprising as your f << output line only outputs a single value from mImage2D (you need to loop over and output all of the values)

Comment: I have rewritten the last part as appending the file with every value being generated in the loop. However, this part of the above code which has the loop is still non functional.